# Performance of DIM1 Repa Array vs Vector

Tags: haskell, vector, repa

I've written a program to process a large amount of data samples using [Repa](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-3.4.1.2/docs/Data-Array-Repa.html). Performance is key for this program. A large part of the operations require parallel maps/folds over a multi-dimensional arrays and `Repa` is perfect for this. However, there is still a part of my program that only uses one-dimensional arrays and doesn't require parallelism (i.e. overhead of parallelism would harm performance). Some of these operations require functions like `take` or `fold`s with custom accumulators, which `Repa` doesn't support. So I'm writing these operations myself by iterating over the `Repa` array.

Am I better off re-writing these operations by using [Vector](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html) instead of `Repa`? Would they result in better performance?

I've read somewhere that one-dimensional `Repa` arrays are implemented as `Vector`s 'under the hood' so I doubt that `Vector`s result in better performance. On the other hand, `Vector` does have some nice built-in functions that I could use instead of writing them myself.

Comment: Repa uses Unboxed(`U`) or Storable(`F`) Vector for all dimensions under the hood, not just `DIM1`. So, I'd say, if you don't need to process those `DIM1` arrays in parallel, you are better of using `vector` package directly.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Every N-dimensional Array is a Vector under the hood. Its only the shape that changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've implemented some parts of my program with `Data.Vector.Unboxed` instead of using one-dimensional `Data.Array.Repa`. Except for some minor improvements, the algorithms are the same. `Data.Vector.Unboxed` seems to be 4 times faster than one-dimensional `Data.Array.Repa` for sequential operations.